# string replace for special character

Tags: c#, .net

I have string as like the following `\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0`. I would like to replace the `\` symbol in between the string

Could anybody tell me how I can replace or remove those `\` back slash from that string.

I have used string replace with `@` symbol ex: `string.Replace(@"\","")` & also used `string.Trim('\0')` and `string.TrimEnd('\0')`

Tell me how I can remove those special character from the symbol.

Vinay

Answer (score 3):

If you tried `s.Replace(@"\", "")` and this didn't yield the expected results it means that in reality there is no `\` character in your actual string. It is what you see in Visual Studio debugger. The actual string maybe contains the 0 byte. To remove it you could:

```
string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 });
s = s.Trim('\0');
```

Notice that because of the strings being immutable in .NET you need to reassign the string to the result of the [`Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx) method as it doesn't modify the original string.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `String.Replace("\\","")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var str=@"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
str.Replace(@"\","");
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me without issues:

```
string s1 = @"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
string s2 = s1.Replace("\\", "");
Console.WriteLine(s2);
```

Output:

```
00000000
```